# How do I prove that $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ purely based on $\sin x$ as a series (so without using the mean value theorem or derivatives).

$\sin x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$

So far, I have shown that $\sin x \in [-1,1]$ and therefore the statement is true for all $|x| \geq 1$. I was also able to show that the statement holds for $x \in [0,1]$ based on the fact that $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is monotonically decreasing in $x \in [0,2]$, due to $x \leq n + 1$, combined with the fact that $\sin x$ is alternating.

My problem arises when I try to apply the same logic for $x \in [-1,0]$. Could anyone give me an idea on how to do this? Can I even do this based on the series definition?

Comment: how you shown that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I can use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there: if $x\in [-1,0]$ then $|\sin x|=|\sin(-x)|\leq |-x|=|x|$, since $-x \in [0,1]$.